# Ionic 3 : Push notification do specific action on click

Tags: angular, push-notification, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

I use **FCM** to provide push notification for my Ionic 3 App (iOS and Android).

I want to know if it's possible to do a specific action when the app is open by click on a push notification ?

**Ex :** My app is closed on my smartphone, I receive a push notification "You have a new message". I tap the notification and my app opens to the message.

And more, is it possible to have buttons to interact with the notification ?

Something like this :

[image]